My Jquery table is only summerizing the first row in the table
i got a table that i want to summarize the values in the cells of each row for each product and day, The thing is that it works, but only on the first row, and the rest of the values gets 0. i think it may be connected to that each product is expandable and the values to the left of the table i created maybe not yet set? because the calculations of the first row is always shown and then the user must expand each product to see the rest of the data. Its an older system and its written in Jquery. My code looks like this:
function calculateAndDisplayTotals() {

    createSummaTotalTableHead();
    createSummaTotalTableBody();
}

function createSummaTotalTableHead() {
    const rowElements = document.querySelectorAll('#tblResult > thead > tr');

    const sectionHeader = rowElements[0];
    const columnsHeaderElement = document.createElement('th');
    columnsHeaderElement.innerHTML = 'Summa totalt';
    columnsHeaderElement.classList.add('fatborder');
    columnsHeaderElement.setAttribute('colspan', '7');
    sectionHeader.appendChild(columnsHeaderElement);

    const columnHeaders = rowElements[1];
    const headerCol1 = document.createElement('th');
    const headerCol2 = document.createElement('th');
    const headerCol3 = document.createElement('th');
    const headerCol4 = document.createElement('th');
    const headerCol5 = document.createElement('th');
    const headerCol6 = document.createElement('th');
    const headerCol7 = document.createElement('th');
    headerCol1.innerHTML = 'Tillgängligt';
    headerCol2.innerHTML = 'Beställt To';
    headerCol3.innerHTML = 'Utfall TO';
    headerCol4.innerHTML = 'Antal per GE';
    headerCol5.innerHTML = 'Detalj TO';
    headerCol6.innerHTML = 'Antal utfall TO';
    headerCol7.innerHTML = 'Diff';
    columnHeaders.appendChild(headerCol1);
    columnHeaders.appendChild(headerCol2);
    columnHeaders.appendChild(headerCol3);
    columnHeaders.appendChild(headerCol4);
    columnHeaders.appendChild(headerCol5);
    columnHeaders.appendChild(headerCol6);
    columnHeaders.appendChild(headerCol7);
}

function createSummaTotalTableBody() {

    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#tblResult > tbody > tr')

    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const row = rows[i];
        const tillgangligtCol = row.querySelectorAll('.tillgangligtCol');
        const bestalltToCol = row.querySelectorAll('.bestalltToCol');
        const utafallToCol = row.querySelectorAll('.utafallToCol');
        const antalPerGeCol = row.querySelectorAll('.antalPerGeCol');
        const antalDetaljToCol = row.querySelectorAll('.antalDetaljTo');
        const antalUtfallToCol = row.querySelectorAll('.antalUtfallToCol');

        const sumTillgangligt = Array.from(tillgangligtCol).map(i => parseInt(i.innerHTML)).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + (isNaN(a) ? 0 : a), 0);
        const sumBestalltTo = Array.from(bestalltToCol).map(i => parseInt(i.innerHTML)).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + (isNaN(a) ? 0 : a), 0);
        const sumUtafallTo = Array.from(utafallToCol).map(i => parseInt(i.innerHTML)).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + (isNaN(a) ? 0 : a), 0);
        const sumAntalPerGe = Array.from(antalPerGeCol).map(i => parseInt(i.innerHTML)).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + (isNaN(a) ? 0 : a), 0);
        const sumAntalDetaljTo = Array.from(antalDetaljToCol).map(i => parseInt(i.innerHTML)).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + (isNaN(a) ? 0 : a), 0);
        const sumAntalUtfallToCol = Array.from(antalUtfallToCol).map(i => parseInt(i.innerHTML)).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + (isNaN(a) ? 0 : a), 0);

        const tillgangligtColumn = document.createElement('td');
        const bestalltToColumn = document.createElement('td');
        const utfallTOColumn = document.createElement('td');
        const antalPerGEColumn = document.createElement('td');
        const detaljToColumn = document.createElement('td');
        const antalUtfallTOColumn = document.createElement('td');
        const diffColumn = document.createElement('td');

        tillgangligtColumn.innerHTML = sumTillgangligt;
        bestalltToColumn.innerHTML = sumBestalltTo;
        utfallTOColumn.innerHTML = sumUtafallTo;
        antalPerGEColumn.innerHTML = sumAntalPerGe;
        detaljToColumn.innerHTML = sumAntalDetaljTo;
        antalUtfallTOColumn.innerHTML = sumAntalUtfallToCol;
        diffColumn.innerHTML = 0;

        row.appendChild(tillgangligtColumn);
        row.appendChild(bestalltToColumn);
        row.appendChild(utfallTOColumn);
        row.appendChild(antalPerGEColumn);
        row.appendChild(detaljToColumn);
        row.appendChild(antalUtfallTOColumn);
        row.appendChild(diffColumn);

    }
}

I call in the code calculateAndDisplayTotals() at the end of the calculations are done, and i know it works correctly beckause it calculates the rows to the left correctly, but note the rows that must be expanded, those are all 0.
I have tried to call the method calculateAndDisplayTotals() in different places with no luck and i think i must somehow call the method when i expand the rows showehow? as it is now, those rows that is expanded after the creation of the table is 0 in every row.
this is how it looks when loaded
and this is how it looks expanded:

the values to the left of the table i created maybe not yet set <== likely - we can't tell from the code you posted if that is indeed the case - you need to do some debugging - i.e. log out the values your code is seeing - the fact that you call it a "jquery table" and there is absolutely no jquery in the code you posted, suggests the issue is with code you haven't posted
